# preg_match do not allow the last character to be underscore or dash

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex which works nicely for usernames.
I want to tweak it somewhat to stop -_ characters from being used as the first/last character of a username. But, allow them elsewhere in the username.

This is what I have so far.

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}+$/', $user)){
    echo 'not valid';
} else {
    echo "is valid username";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lookarounds`.

```
^(?![_-])[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}(?<![_-])$
```

Also you dont need `+` after `{1,16}`

Answer (score 3):

That `+` at the end of your regex should actually throw an error. Just remove it.

Use this, plain and simple:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,14}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```